# Delegate doesn't works on IE? A very strange behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I notice that this my own [page](http://www.gabbatracklistworld.com/wrong.php) doesnt work at all on IE8 : try to click on `Add Category`, than on `Create Category` : you should get an alert. In fact that's not happens on my IE8. Chrome, Firefox, all ok.

Why? This is the whole code :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"> 
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="it"> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <title>The GTW Database</title>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="settings/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mgmt/mgmt_javascript.js"></script>          
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="settings/style.css" title="Style" media="all" /> 
</head> 

<body> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#addCategory').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#addCategoryForm').toggle();
            }); 

            $("#addCategoryForm").delegate("form[name=categoryForm]", "submit", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("Yeah, I'm In");
            }); 
        });
    </script>   

    <div class="main_content_remark"> 
        <div class="back1"> 
            Categories
        </div> 

        <div class="back2"> 
            <a id="addCategory" class="lblueb" href="#">Add Category</a> 
        </div> 
    </div> 

    <div class="main_content_remark" id="addCategoryForm" style="display:none; height:32px;"> 
        <form method='post' name="categoryForm"> 
            <div class="categoryName"> 
                <div class="categoryName1"> 
                    Name
                </div> 

                <div class="categoryName2"> 
                    <input type="text" maxlength="50" name="name" class="input400" /> 
                </div> 

                <div class="categoryName3"> 
                    &nbsp;
                </div> 

                <div class="categoryName4"> 
                    <input type="submit" value="Create Category" /> 
                </div>                  
            </div> 
        </form>         
    </div> 
</body>
```

Hope you can help me. It's really strange... the same method works perfectly in other pages...

Comment: Which version IE are you experiencing this problem with? I tried IE 7 and 8 and had no issues with it. Could you try http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/w4jnM/ and see if it works for you?

Comment: Something else on your script is messing up the form event handler. I tried the same thing on IE 7, 8 and 9 and I get the caio. Please provide more information. Like other scripts/markup on have on your page.

Comment: Done! Check the whole code and the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `[name=categoryForm]` which confuses IE7,8. Change it to an ID or if this form is the only form inside `#addCategoryForm` then just write:

```
$("#addCategoryForm").delegate("form", "submit", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Yeah, I'm In");
        });
```

Comment: Yeah you are right. It's really strange anyway : in some other pages I use this strategy, and it works without problem. :O